# Why Django tries to use MySQL instead of sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

My problem is this: When I try to do the migrations, it gives me the following error:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/jenifer/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 21, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Thing is, I've never told django to use MySQL, in fact, the settings.py states that it has to use SQLite:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gestlote.db'),
    }

}
```

I've alreay tried to reinstall django, upgrade it, pip3 install pysqlite, but nothing seems to work.
So please, help me

Comment: Are you sure it is working with the correct `settings.py`? DId you remove the `*.pyc` files?

Comment: Yes, it's the right settings.py and also tried removing the .pyc files, but still doesn't work

Comment: looks like you do not have virtual environment set up and Django is using your default copy of Python

Comment: yes, I didn't use virtualenv to run this stuff. I will try to use it to see if it works

Comment: In the end I solved the problem reinstalling all the SO. It was a drastic measure, but in desperate times...